# Android Retrofit: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: retrofit, slash

**ERROR:**
When working with Retrofit, the application crashes with the following error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.

```
private const val MAIN_URL = "https://api.main.com"
private const val ADDITIONAL_URL = "/trending"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{/} the whole problem is slash
it should be at the end of the main URL and not at the beginning of the additional.

```
private const val MAIN_URL = "https://api.main.com/"
private const val ADDITIONAL_URL = "trending"
```